# Count the number of prime numbers under a non-negative number - JAVA

Tags: java, boolean, primes

I wrote out code to find the number of prime numbers under a non-negative number, not sure what is wrong with this code:
- When I n = 10, my output is 4 which is correct. (2,3,5,7) - Prime numbers under 10
- When I n = 10000, my output is 3334, while it should be 1229.
Not sure where this code is going wrong and I have spent a lot of time analyzing it.

public static void main (String [] args) {

```
    int n = 10000;
    int counter = 0;

    if (n <= 2) {
            System.out.println("0 prime numbers"); }

    if (n == 3) {
         System.out.println("1 prime number"); }

    counter+=2; //accounts for prime numbers 2 and 3

    for (int x = 4; x < n; x++) { 

            //Started at 4 since I have already checked for 2 and 3
            if (isPrime(x) == true) {
                counter = counter + 1;  }
    }

      System.out.println("The number of prime numbers are " + counter); }

  public static boolean isPrime (int x) {
    if (x % 2 == 0 || x % 3 == 0) {
        return false; }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Well, the problem is that you only consider numbers to be prime if they're not divisible by 2 or 3. Might be time to re-read the [definition of a prime number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number).

Comment: Hint: what should `isPrime(25)` return?

Answer (score 1):

The concept of Prime number: The prime numbers are the natural numbers greater than one that are not products of two smaller numbers.

Maybe this is what you want:

```
public static boolean isPrime(List<Long> primes, long number) {

    if(number < 2) return false;

    for (Long prime : primes) {
        if (number % prime == 0) return false;
    }

    return true;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Long> primes = new ArrayList<>();
    long max = 10000;
    long num = 2;
    while(num < max) {
        if(isPrime(primes, num)) {
            primes.add(num);
        }
        num++;
    }
    System.out.println("count: " + primes.size());
    System.out.println("primes: " + primes);
}
```

the output of code above:

count: 1229

primes: [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239, 241, 251, 257, 263, 269, 271, 277, 281, 283, 293, 307, 311, 313, 317, 331, 337, 347, 349, 353, 359, 367, 373, 379, 383, 389, 397, 401, 409, 419, 421, 431, 433, 439, 443, 449, 457, 461, 463, 467, 479, 487, 491, 499, 503, 509, 521, 523, 541, 547, 557, 563, 569, 571, 577, 587, 593, 599, 601, 607, 613, 617, 619, 631, 641, 643, 647, 653, 659, 661, 673, 677, 683, 691, 701, 709, 719, 727, 733, 739, 743, 751, 757, 761, 769, 773, 787, 797, 809, 811, 821, 823, 827, 829, 839, 853, 857, 859, 863, 877, 881, 883, 887, 907, 911, 919, 929, 937, 941, 947, 953, 967, 971, 977, 983, 991, 997, 1009, 1013, ....

9613, 9619, 9623, 9629, 9631, 9643, 9649, 9661, 9677, 9679, 9689, 9697, 9719, 9721, 9733, 9739, 9743, 9749, 9767, 9769, 9781, 9787, 9791, 9803, 9811, 9817, 9829, 9833, 9839, 9851, 9857, 9859, 9871, 9883, 9887, 9901, 9907, 9923, 9929, 9931, 9941, 9949, 9967, 9973]

Answer (score 0):

Replace your isPrime function with the following:

```
boolean isPrime(int n) {
  //check if n is a multiple of 2
  if (n%2==0) return false;
  //if not, then just check the odds
  for(int i=3;i*i<=n;i+=2) {
    if(n%i==0)
        return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

I got this solutions from [here](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-determine-a-prime-number-in-java/). Basically, if a number is not divisible by two, it won't be divisible by any other even number. So, just check to see if it's divisible by any odd number. This will produce the correct answer and cut your search time in half.

Comment: Your for loop can stop at `sqrt(n)`

Comment: agree with **@selbie**. In terms of number of iterations (made by `for`-loop), `i * i <= n` will perform same as `i <= sqrt(n)`. However considering that optimiser will cache the value of `sqrt(n)` resulting in test expression breaking down into a simple *comparison operation* `<=`, `sqrt(n)` would likely perform better for large value of `n`

Comment: Your `if (n%2==0) return false;` fails if `n==2`.  I prefer to use `if (n%2==0) return n==2;` which works for all non-negative even numbers including 2.